# How can i generate a 100 by 6 array in R with random numbers in it?

Tags: arrays, r, random

For example if I try this, the numbers are not going to be random, it generates 6 random numbers, then repeat it.

```
Z <- array(sample(1:100, 6, replace=T), c(100,6))
```

any ideas?

Comment: Why do you expect `sample` to return more than 6 random numbers when you set the `size=6`?

Comment: `sample` doesn't generate random numbers, it picks numbers _at random_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question didn't specify what sort of random numbers you want, but if you want to fill the array with random integers between 1 and 100, then this will do that for you:
`Z <- array(sample(1:100, 600, replace=T), c(100,6))`

If you actually want random draws between 0 and 1, you just do
`Z<-array(runif(600), c(100,6))`

The key thing is that you need to draw 600 random numbers and then use array to put them in a matrix.